# Batch command to restrict any admin member from remote login

Tags: batch-file

I want to restrict an newly/existing added user form remote login, but the same user is a member of ADMIN group on the system.

Is it possible and if , please tell me the command line option. I tried using 
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" user_name /Delete
But since the user is an Admin member so it seems it doesn't work :(.

Please suggest me any possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative way, you could use wmic for that:

Execute against many machines at once and save list as nicely formatted html table (among other formats):

```
wmic /node:@servers.txt /output:services.html service get caption /format:htable
```

Of course you may query many more attributes besides names/captions.